# remove index.php from homepage after link directs to it

Tags: php

in my pages the logo is a link to the homepage. initially in the homepage in the url bar its just written localhost but after i click on the link and go back to index.php, its written in th url bar, localhost/index.php. how do i remove index.php from there? But not use the rewrite function in the .htaccess.

in my pages the logo is a link to the homepage. initially in the homepage in the url bar its just written localhost but after i click on the link and go back to index.php, its written in th url bar, localhost/index.php. how do i remove index.php from there? But not use the rewrite function in the .htaccess.

Comment: What do your links look like? I guess they include `index.php` ?

Comment: you want to need get ROOT URL for both live site or localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `/` as your `href`

```
<a href="/"><img src="mylogo.png" /></a>
```